# Inverse Fourier transform of $\frac{\cos(x)}{x^2} $

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, signal-processing

I am stuck in the integral of an inverse Fourier transform in an exercise of a graduate signals class.

I am trying to compute the inverse Fourier Transform for the signal given below. I tried regular integration techniques to calculate the inverse transform:

$$ x(t) = \frac{1}{2π} \int_{- \infty}^{+ \infty} { Χ(ω) e^{iωt} dω} = \frac{1}{2π} \int_{- \infty}^{+ \infty} { \frac{\cos(ω)}{ω^2} e^{iωt} dω}  $$

but they do not work. So what is the right answer?

Summarizing the question:

Find the signal whose Fourier transform is

$$ X(Ω) = \frac{\cos(Ω)}{Ω^2} $$

What is the inverse Fourier transform of the above X(Ω)?

Comment: What have you tried? Please include your attempts.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: @CrSb0001 I tried integrating $\frac{cos(x)}{x^2}$ over x, but it does not go anywhere. Integrating by parts leaves more unsolved integrals, etc. I can include some here but I posted the question with no attempts to get a good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $f(x)=\frac{\cos(x)}{x^2}$ is not locally integrable and is not, therefore, a tempered distribution.  We can define, however, a distribution that permits our defining the Fourier Transform.  We define the distribution $\left(\psi\right)_{D}=\left(\frac{\cos(x)}{x^2}\right)_{D}$ such that for any $\phi\in \mathbb{S}$,

$$\left(\left(\psi\right)_{D},\phi\right)=\text{PV}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos(x)}{x^2}\left(\phi(x)-\phi(0)-\phi'(0)x\right)\,dx\tag1$$

Equipped with $(1)$, we proceed to find the Fourier Transform of $\left(\psi\right)_{D}$.

---

We see that

$$\begin{align}
\langle \mathscr{F}\{\left(\psi\right)_{D}\},\phi\rangle&=\langle \left(\psi\right)_{D},\mathscr{F}\{\phi\}\rangle\\\\
&=\text{PV}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos(x)}{x^2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(k)\left(e^{ikx}-1-ix\right)\,dk\,dx\\\\
&=2\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(x)}{x^2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(k)\left(\cos(kx)-1\right)\,dk\,dx\\\\
&=-2\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(k)\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(x)(1-\cos(kx))}{x^2}\,dx\,dk\\\\
&=-\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(k)\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos((k+1)x)+\cos((k-1)x)}{x}\,dx\,dk\\\\
&=-\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(k)\int_0^\infty \frac{(k+1)\sin((k+1)x)+(k-1)\sin((k-1)x)}{x}\,dx\,dk\\\\
&=-\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(k) \frac\pi 2\left((k+1)\text{sgn}(k+1)+(k-1)\text{sgn}(k-1)\right)\,dk
\end{align}$$

Therefore, in distribution we see that

$$\mathscr{F}\{\left(\psi\right)_{D}\}=-\frac\pi2 \left((k+1)\text{sgn}(k+1)+(k-1)\text{sgn}(k-1)\right)$$

Comment: Which can be written $-\frac{\pi}{2}(|k+1|+|k-1|).$

Comment: @md2perpe Indeed it can.

Comment: very interesting solution, thank you! I will upvote.

Comment: @spiros You're welcome.   My pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a method that gives the solution up to an additive constant ($B$ in the result below).

I will skip constant factors. Some of those depend of the used definition of the Fourier transform.

The inverse Fourier transform of $\Omega^2 X(\Omega) = \cos\Omega$ is
$$-x''(t) = \delta(t-1)+\delta(t+1).$$
Therefore,
$$x(t) = -\frac12 (|t-1|+|t+1|) + At + B,$$
where $A$ and $B$ are constants. However, since $X(\Omega)$ is even, so must be $x(t).$ Therefore $A=0.$

Comment: Aren't you missing a $\frac12$ factor in the ODE?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo. I have skipped several constant factors.

Comment: I read the "I will skip constant factors" part only now.  Why not use $\propto$ instead of the misleading $=$?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo. Laziness.